# #include <malloc.h> -- Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, malloc

I have an interesting problem where I can't include malloc.h in my project.

I need malloc.h for Paul Nettle's mmgr tool (I'm not keen on using instruments)

Problem is I can't find the system library for memalign.

Xcode keeps failing because it cannot this definition & neither can I.

Anyone else seen this?!

Comment: iOS or Mac? Also, what's your objection to Instruments?

Comment: There's no such thing as "malloc.h" in the standard C language. If whatever system you're used to has it, well, that's just a quirk of that system. start using stdlib.h like KushaIP said below.

Comment: its for iOS. I prefer using cross-platform tools as the project is not iPhone only

Comment: But you're perfectly OK using some other tool that expects to find a non-standard header? Either way, what makes you think using Instruments to diagnose a memory problem will somehow "infect" your project code and make it iPhone-only?

Comment: `man memalign` --> `#include <stdlib.h>` .. <5 seconds

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you just need to use `malloc` then you can grab it from the stdlib like so:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Otherwise, you can directly call `malloc.h` like so:

```
#include <malloc/malloc.h>
```

**EDIT:**

A `posix_memalign()` exists in `stdlib.h`. The implementation looks like:

```
int posix_memalign(void **, size_t, size_t);
```

Perhaps you can make an alias to this and use it?

Comment: Its not malloc I need. Its memalign.

Comment: Ive tried including both of the above & neither contains a prototype for memalign

Comment: You could remap it to use posix_memalign. See my edit to the question.